# How to check user roles in a filter?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using `play framework 2.8.x` and I need to add some check for some pages if user hasn't accessed to this page I have to reject this request and I thought I can use the filters but I don't know how to reject an incoming request in the filter. My filter looks like the following:

```
public class PageAccessFilter extends Filter {
    @Inject
    public PageAccessFilter(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> next, Http.RequestHeader rh) {

        return next.apply(rh); // how can I reject request?
    }
}
```

How can I reject the intomming request with some status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Just return forbidden():

```
@Override
public CompletionStage<Result> apply(Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> next, Http.RequestHeader rh) {

    if (your auth check failed) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.forbidden());
    }
    return next.apply(rh); 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me because of ```play.mvc.Results.forbidden``` return ```Result``` object instead ```CompletionStage<Result>```